# Android Studio (Unable to find Google API Image) In Virtual Device Configuration

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am trying to use Google Maps in my AVD.

To do this I need to download a system image for my emulator, however I am unable to find a target image Android Studio "with Google API" for API level 17, 18 or 19.

I am checking via "Tools" -> "Android" -> "AVD Manager" (and editing my Nexus 5 system image from here).

I have tried refreshing the downloadable system images.  Adding "Google Play Services" and "Google Play Repository" with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to launch the avd manager and download one of the google api system images with google api add-on. Unfortunately they tend to be "arm" only around that API level.  You're only option in that range is 18.  I hightlighted the 16 and 18 level that would work.  If you go to 21 you can get x86_64 bit which should be faster. Your 17 targeted code will work, but if you want to test 17 specific code it of course won't and you'll need to have an actual device.

Note the items highlighted in green.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  As I want to target 17, I have already installed the Google API add on.  How is my AVD emulator meant to interact with this add on however?  I am not able to load the image on the emulator, so can the add-on help me load google aps?

Comment: I'm going to install the 17 emulator and let you know if it works for me.

Comment: @NormanBentley I've updated the answer for you.  Looks like there are some api levels that just don't have the google api AVDs available.

Comment: Thanks Cory, decided to just use my device and its working like a charm.  Thanks for the help.